# Filter by different or multiple sources in react admin list

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Is there any way to filter react admin lists by multiple sources, or to change the source on the front end with react admin? I've tried running the source as a state variable, but when updated it only adds to the query instead of replacing it.

Example filter list

```
const UserFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search By ID" source="uid" alwaysOn />
  </Filter>
);

export const UserList = (props) => (
  <List {...props} filters={<UserFilter />}>
    <Datagrid>
      <RichTextField label="User ID" source="uid" />
      <RichTextField label="Email" source="email" />
      <RichTextField label="Admin" source="isAdmin" />
      <ShowButton label="" />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Comment: The term "source" is ambiguous in your question. Could you describe what you're trying to do (i.e. which criteria you want to apply to the list search)? React-admin does support multi-criteria filters. Also, the filter documentation on react-admin is pretty extensive, make sure you read it to use the right terms so the community understand your request. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#filtering-the-list

Comment: Source is a property for textinput that controls the filter, see the example in the post.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you describe what UI you would like the user to see, and what calls to the dataProvider should result from their interactions?